# How can I solve the issue of my React site going blank after a build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, build

My react site went blank after running build

I trying to deploy React site to product on running build, however when I open the old browser tab (which is opening my old react site) I get a blank page.

I inspected it on my phone and got an error like below image. Browser is still loading the old chunk file.

[image]

When I **reload** the page, I got my new web. Can who help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Wait I got confused, 1. is it not updating in your old tab (stuck cache?), 2. is it not working on your phone, 3. is it working after a refresh?

Comment: And then a blank page is in your title? Even then you still need to provide more details and also clarify the real error.

Comment: @Aleksandar 
1. Old tab it will find and load the old build file. However, after building this file doesn't exist anymore so now I get a blank page.
2. It doesn't work with many devices (android, ios, laptop,...) that used to have web tabs before build.
3. Yes. It will be working after I reload the old tab.

Comment: When I connect to my phone and debug. I get this error. 
https://pasteboard.co/WFPlWhSGTtM0.png

Current tab is loading chunk file: main.efafbcdd.js (https://pasteboard.co/9IoX9bwKOyKl.png). 

However, after running build, my react app generated new chunk file: main.3e5f583c.js. The below image captures my react web after clicking reload (https://pasteboard.co/XASKcN6waKRf.png)